# How to send this HTTP POST packet to a website?

Tags: php

Basically, the title says it. I need to figure out how to send this HTTP POST request to another website. (It is my friends, therefor I don't own it)

```
    <html>
    <body>
            <form method="post">
                    <input type="hidden"
                    <?php
                            echo " value='";
                            for($i=0;$i<2147483648;$i++)
                                    {
                                            echo "a";
                                    }
                            echo "'";
                    ?>
                    >
                    <input type="submit">
            </form>
<?php if(isset($_POST['test'])){
    echo $_POST['test'];
}
?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm I missing the JAVA part? I appears like a PHP question.

Comment: Oops, did I put this in the Java section?

Comment: What you've posted is a php script, not a post request. If all you want to do is send requests, don't bother with Java, just use [`curl`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL), or a tool like [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL).

Comment: What does this PHP code do, then?

Comment: Pull data from post variable test. The first part is a form with a hidden field and and loop.

Comment: How do I use cURL? I am not exactly familiar with this kind of thing, but I see it is a library of sorts. If so, where do I use these commands?

Comment: How did you come up with this code? Did you pull it from the internet or did you write it yourself.

Comment: I asked someone how I might send a HTTP POST request that uses a larger amount of data (around 2GB) so as to test our site. He wrote this, I only do Java.

Comment: Are you trying to submit form data to another php file on a different server? normally if its on the same server you need to set the action to point to the file your posting to.. example <form  action="fileto postto.php" method="post">

Comment: I think that your loop will take a lot of time to complete and will lead to a time out, before you are able to send 2GB.

Comment: Why do you like to test this site with a 2GB data request? Normally you will use POST / GET for far less amount of data.

Comment: if you intent to use php you should learn the basics first.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, your code creates a small webpage. The webpage uses an HTML `form` to send data to a website.

You can change the location and method of this data by editing the `<form>` tag. Currently, it uses `post` (as opposed to `get`) and it doesn't have a destination url. If there is no destination, then it will send the data to itself. You can set a destination with the `action` attribute, like this:

```
<form method="post" action="http://example.com/pagename">
```

Once you are done, view this page in a browser. You should see a single button. Once you click it, it will post the data to whatever `action` is set to.

**EDIT**

It looks like you are trying to send a lot of data to this server. This might not work as intended with just an HTML form.

An alternate way to do this is to use `cURL`. `cURL` lets you create `POST` data within the code of a PHP page. It might be more practical to take a large file (like a movie or something) and `POST` it to your friend's server like this:

```
<?php 
//  Code from http://forums.devshed.com/php-development-5/php-curl-send-a-file-533233.html

//  write the path to your file here:
$filename = 'C:/myenormousfile.avi';

//  write the url to your friend's site here:
$url = 'http://example.com/filename';

$file_to_upload = array('file_contents'=>'@' . $filename); 
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $file_to_upload); 
$result=curl_exec ($ch); 
curl_close ($ch); 
echo $result; 
?>
```

Save this into a `.php` file, and view the file through your localhost. If it works correctly, then it will attempt to `POST` the file to your friend's site. It will then show text that indicates if the upload was successful or not.

**EDIT #2**

This might be a simpler approach. It is an HTML webpage, so the only thing you would need to do would be to save this code into a `.html` file, and look at it in any browser: you wouldn't need to do anything with `PHP` or web servers. This page will let you pick a file (again, you should use it to pick a large file), and POST it to your friend's website. The file can be up to ~4 GB in size. You can change the `action` attribute of the `<form>` element to send the file to a different location.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head><title>Pick a File and POST it to your Friend&apos;s Server</title></head>
<body>
<form action="http://www.example.com/pagename" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="5000000" />
<input type="file" name="uploadField" />
<input type="submit" value="Go" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Paste this into a file, save it as `post.html`, then look at the file in Windows Explorer. Then right click on the file and open it with a browser. You should see a "Browse..." button and a button that says "Go". Use "Browse..." to pick an enormous file, then click "Go" and see what happens.

Comment: How do I download cURL or use it? I have virtually no experience with that. Also, yes it is a very large file I am sending through the POST. Also, could you possible show me what I would add to send to say... www.example.com?? Thank you, any helpful advice or statements is appreciated.

Comment: So, from what I can gather, it would look something similar to this? http://imgur.com/rkkBtei.jpg

Comment: It sounds like you're a bit new to PHP as well. Your image contains the code that you'll need to build a small webpage. I wouldn't bother with the `iframe` stuff, since you'll want to see if this is working in real time. You'll need to run this webpage through your `localhost`. Try searching for a "Hello World" PHP example to get an idea of how to do this. If it works correctly, then the page should take a while to load, then you'll see a button. Once you click it, then the page will wait for a moment, then send you to your friend's page. It should appear as if the site is loading for a while.

Comment: @NoneNone : You can see a brief introduction to cURL here: http://www.phpbuilder.com/columns/ian_gilfillan20050525.php3 . I don't know much about installing cURL, so you'll have to find a tutorial for that. Once it is installed, you take the code from the second code block, save it as a .php file, then view that file in your browser through a web server. You can change the file and url by changing the 5th and 8th lines of code. If it works correctly, the page will take a while to load (maybe a minute? it depends), then should show some text (I forget what, exactly).

Comment: @NoneNone : I updated this answer with a third idea. This idea only requires HTML, which means no PHP, no cURL, and no coding.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Chris

You can use full path in action and use target if you can't redirected to this URL

```
<form method="post" action="http://example.com/pagename" target="myIframe">

<iframe name="myIframe" style="display:none"></iframe>
```

**EDITED**

[image]

This image ilustrate both solutions

Comment: No if you use cURL you can copy the post content and send it to another server. By my example you will send all data directly to url destination. It's more simple to implement, but if you wants to copy the post content before send to another server you will need cURL

Comment: How do I obtain cURL? From what I can see there is no download, so I find myself doubting it is a file.

Comment: cURL in this context it's a PHP extension. http://php.net/manual/en/curl.installation.php